# Setup weighted redirect in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have a server making request to Server A. Now I need to direct 25% of all requests coming to Server A -> Server B. So 75% coming to A other 25 to B server

I created a CName with weighted record policy within AWS Hosted zone uner this url

weightedredirect.mydomain.com

and currently I you reach weightedredirect.mydomain.com - 75% comes to A and another 25% to B server, but if you put it in browser, you've got an SSL certificate error saying that certificate for weightedredirect.mydomain.com should be the same as for A or B server which is not I want actually.

So the question is how I can preallocate some url in my hosted zone and have this percentage redirect with no SSL issue in AWS?

Comment: show the exact error.  sounds like you're wanting to connect https to A or B both with the name weightedredirect.mydomain.com .  they both need a certificate that matches that name for that to work.

Comment: @erik258 yes, you're right. But unfortunately Server A and Server B is not under my control.

Comment: If those servers are not under your control and you want to use your own DNS name AND you want to use HTTPS, then you can't. They aren't your servers, so the certificates won't match.